# Preventing emacsclient -c from bringing both Emacs frames to the front

Tags: emacsclient

**Environment** Cygwin, emacs-w32 variant.

**Use case** Setting up my editor for git commits from the terminal.

**Problem**
When I do a git commit from a terminal, I have it setup to do

```
emacsclient -c
```

I get a new frame as expected, and Emacs brings it to the front and focuses it correctly. However, it also brings to the front (but without focusing), my main Emacs window. So now I have two Emacs frames on top, indeed I can see the buffer I am editing in both of them.

By main Emacs window, I mean the one that I usually start when I login. This is annoying, because I often minimize that window while I work on other things.

I suspect it may be caused because I call `server-start` in my .emacs file, but I don't know a way to work around it.

**Aim**
I really just want to popup the new frame, leaving the old frame completely alone, then I will close the new frame after typing in my git commit message. It's sort of a "throw-away, quick edit", completely focused on the job in hand.